# GPU / Graphics profiler for non Android Embedded systems

Tags: graphics, gpu, profiling, mali

I have a non-Android Embedded system which uses Embedded Linux based OS. It has a Mali GPU and I need to profile GPU performance. Some options were DS5 Streamline and Mali Graphics debugger, but it seems tailored for Android (with adb). Is there any generic GPU profiling tool which I can use?

Comment: What is your exact SoC chip used for the system? Which is exact GPU model? Can you write the board model? What is the Linux version (`uname -srvmpio`, `lsb_release -a`)? What is the graphic solution used, is it Xorg server? GPU profiling is specific to GPU vendors and generations.

Answer (score 2):

Streamline (DS version) does support Linux-based targets. On the [Streamline documentation page](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/graphics-and-gaming/arm-mobile-studio/learn/streamline-documentation) you'll find near the bottom a link to the doc for [setting up a Linux-based target](https://developer.arm.com/docs/101814/latest).